# Which probability to calculate?

Tags: probability

I was wondering if someone could help me with the probability question stated below.

The probability that a particular moth trap $A$, collects $r$ moths overnight is given by $(1-\alpha)\alpha^r$ for  $r=0,1,\ldots$ with $0<\alpha<1$. For trap $B$ the probability is $(1-\beta)\beta^r$ for $r=0,1,\ldots$ with $0<\beta<1$., independently of trap $A$. Show that 
The probability that the traps collect equal number of moths is 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)}{1-\alpha\beta}
\end{equation*}
The probability that trap $A$ collects more moths than trap $B$ is given by 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\alpha(1-\beta)}{1-\alpha\beta}
\end{equation*}

I have shown the first part, by using the formula for an infinite geometric series. But I do not know how to show the second part. In particular, I am confused what probability I should consider $P(R_A>r_B|R_B=r_B)$ or $P(R_A>r_B$ and $R_B=r_B)$ where $R_i,i=A,B$ are random variables denoting the number of moths trapped by $A$ and $B$ respectively. I am very confused which of these two probabilities I should compute and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate $\Pr(R_A\gt r)$ for an arbitrary value of $r$. In each case you are summing infinite geometric series, and the expression for the sum is relatively simple. Once you have found the answer for $r=0$, the sum for arbitrary $r$ is easy to write down.

Then find
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \Pr(R_B=r)\Pr(R_A\gt r).$$
This sum will be another infinite geometric series.